Validating composite signatures with the Safe's CompatibilityFallbackHandler
In the context of a protocol that creates Safes for its users: I'm trying to determine if I can safely assume that most external protocols implementing ERC-1271 will correctly treat a Safe's signature like a contract signature, or if I need to account for the possibility of external contracts treating them like composite owner signatures (i.e., the concatenated signatures of a sufficient threshold of Safe owners) when they attempt to validate them.
In version 1.4.1 of the Safe, the validation of composite signatures is only supported in what the documentation calls a "legacy" version of the isValidSignature function (and is not available in the UI). However, there have been recent changes to the CompatibilityFallbackHandler that have removed this documentation and combined the two functions, so I'm wondering whether this implies it's a pattern that is becoming more common.

The "legacy" checkSignature was not combined, but simply moved at the Safe.sol contract level. The CompatibilityFallbackHandler contract was updated to only include the "non-legacy" version. The change affects Safe smart contract owners, and not external protocols.
Previously, a Safe with a smart contract owner would call the "legacy" isValidSignature method on the smart contract owner but was changed to be the current ERC-1271 standard.
Note that callers to the Safe should not require any changes as the new Safe version and compatibility fallback handler continue to support both the current ERC-1271 and legacy-1271 standard.
So the signatures emitted by a Safe are always contract signatures. These are not to be confused with signatures emitted by a Safe owner to approve a transaction, which are always concatenated.
Please let me know if that answered your question! Thanks in advance 
Best, Louis

Thanks Louis, that makes perfect sense!

Happy to see that it answered your question! Don't hesitate to mark my answer as the solution to help other builders that might have the same question
